# Does Highchart - Heat map support SUM of values?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I was looking for something like below 
[image]

Is there is any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way could be to add another series with summed values of rows and columns. To avoid default coloring and `colorAxis` interaction it is possible to change options of dataLabel format, tooltip format and data point properties.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9fp7sarx/6/

Another solution could be to added lined axes on opposite sides and with categories set as summed values. Values will not be summed automatically - you would have to set calculate the values yourself or by custom code.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8t2ugtm0/

```
    xAxis: [{
        categories: ['Alexander', 'Marie', 'Maximilian', 'Sophia', 'Lukas', 'Maria', 'Leon', 'Anna', 'Tim', 'Laura']
    },{
        linkedTo: 0,
        opposite: true,
        categories: [34,543,235,34,4,345,123,345,56,337],
        labels: {
            autoRotationLimit: 0
        }
    }],

    yAxis: [{
        categories: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
        title: null
    },{
        linkedTo: 0,
        opposite: true,
        categories: [234,432,123,464,554],
        title: null
    }],
```

Comment: Nice thoughts to accommodate existing features to build up the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You can sum that by adding extra axis (as Kacper mentioned) but catch label formatter and extract current x / y value. Then iterate on serie and sum all points with the same coordinate.

```
xAxis: [{
            categories: ['Alexander', 'Marie', 'Maximilian', 'Sophia', 'Lukas', 'Maria', 'Leon', 'Anna', 'Tim', 'Laura']
        },{
            linkedTo: 0,
            opposite: true,
            tickLength: 0,
            labels: {
                formatter:function() {
                    var chart = this.chart,
                        each = Highcharts.each,
                        series = chart.series[0],
                        sum = 0,
                        x = this.value;

                    each(series.options.data, function(p, i) {
                        if(p[0] === x)
                            sum += p[2]; 
                    });

                    return sum;
                }
            }
        }],

        yAxis: [{
            categories: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
            title: null
        },{
            linkedTo: 0,
            opposite: true,
            tickLength: 0,
            labels: {
                formatter:function() {
                    var chart = this.chart,
                        each = Highcharts.each,
                        series = chart.series[0],
                        sum = 0,
                        x = this.value;
                    each(series.options.data, function(p, i) {
                        if(p[1] === x)
                            sum += p[2]; 
                    });

                    return sum;
                }
            },
            title: null
        }],
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8t2ugtm0/1/

Comment: Your solution helps to build up the sum from client side itself. Thanks for the answer